# View displays nodes that should be excluded by filter

Tags: views

I'm working on the website for my bicycle shop. I've created a series of views that display the different types of bicycles we have: touring bikes, city bikes, etc. There is also a view that displays all the bikes.

In order to hide display of bikes that have been sold already (i.e. have 0 stock), I have the following filter criteria:

Stock: Level (>0) OR
Stock: Active (No)

(There is the provision that if the stock level is not set to active it's ok for the stock to be zero, because there are some products that we don't track the stock of).

When someone buys a bike, the stock is decreased by 1 (to 0, most often), and the bike should then disappear from the view.

Except that it doesn't.

Eg. The first bike on [this page](http://omafiets.com.au/touring-bikes?field_new_secondhand_value=All&sort_by=field_size_value&sort_order=ASC) - if you click on it, it says it's sold, and the stock is set to active, and the stock number is zero.

My question is: why does it still appear in the view? I have cleared the caches, re-created the view... If I create a new view that has no filters except the criteria "Stock level > 0", the aforementioned bicycle with stock=0 still appears!

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: Can you export a view and a couple nodes (including the node type export) and put them on pastebin? I'll be happy to try it out. Also, are you using D7 and are you using any custom `insert()` functions?

Comment: View: http://pastebin.com/xb6hBGYC
Node: http://pastebin.com/SfQmZSpp
Can't seem to figure out exporting the node type...sorry!

Using D7, no custom insert() function as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Use [bundle_copy](https://drupal.org/project/bundle_copy) to export the content type.

Comment: Content type: http://pastebin.com/VpcuiPNr

Comment: Sorry it's taking so long to get back.  Are you using commerce? I cannot import the content because there is a missing content type, "product".  I will need that bundle_copy to move forward as well.

Comment: Yep sorry, using commerce. Product content type: http://pastebin.com/rWtFB0Hv

Answer (score 0):

Your filter says, "if the stock level is greater than 0 (1,2,3,4...) OR stock is not active, don't show the product". You want it to say, "if the stock is equal to 0 ( or <=0 ) OR stock is not active, don't show the product“. In other words: `Stock: Level (=0) OR Stock: Active (No)`

On second thought, if you're not filtering out, you would want `Stock: Level (>0) OR Stock: Active (Yes)` to show all bikes that are active, and have more than 0 in stock.

Comment: The filters in Views are filtering in, not filtering out.

The reason I want to display products for which the stock is not active is that these are items we have lots of. I want to display products that have either:
Stock > 0
OR
Stock: Not active